# Grouped UITableView with custom UILabels in Editing Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, resize

I have a grouped `UITableView` where the user can enter editing mode and delete rows from the table. Each cell of the table has two `UILabels`. When the table enters into editing mode, the custom `UILabels` push to the right and go beyond the right border of the cell.

If I use the standard `cell.textLabel`, the label resizes and stays within the borders of the cell. Ideas about how to do this with the custom `UILabels` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement and use these two UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
– tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

In willBegin, set your UILabel frame to have a smaller width and set the width to normal size on didEndEditing.

For example, if your UILabel is getting pushed 50 pixels out of the boundary, in your methods you do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect newFrame = thisCell.someUILabel.frame;

    newFrame.size.width -= 50;

    thisCell.someUILabel.frame = newFrame;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect newFrame = thisCell.someUILabel.frame;

    newFrame.size.width += 50;

    thisCell.someUILabel.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: This works for one row, but my problem is that when I tap the 'edit' button and the red circles appear next every cell, and this is where my problem comes up. willBeignEditingRowAtIndexPath is invoked only when a single row is selected for deletion.

Comment: Are you using subclassed cells? Or are you adding the UILabels as subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Sounds like you're doing the latter...

Comment: I have added the UILabels as subviews.

Comment: Try subclassing the UITableViewCell and then see if the problem persists.... An added advantage to this is you have a higher level of control over the UILabel subviews as now it's easier to access a specific UILabel in a desired cell.