# Grouped UITableView with custom cells with subviews/layers in editing mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a *grouped* `UITableView` with custom cells (created by subclassing `UITableViewCell`). I add subviews and insert sublayers just like this:

```
[self.contentView addSubview:myUILabel];
```

and

```
[self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:myCALayer];
```

When entering editing mode for deleting rows, the cells move right and `myUILabel` and `myCALayer` *go beyond the borders of the cell*, which looks ugly.

I tried this:

[Grouped UITableView with custom UILabels in Editing Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103973/grouped-uitableview-with-custom-uilabels-in-editing-mode)

... but it didn't help.

What "kind of" worked is to override `setEditing:` in my custom cell

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect oldBounds = self.myCALayer.bounds;
    CGRect newBounds = oldBounds;
    CGPoint oldPosition = self.myCALayer.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = oldPosition;
    //move right
    if (editing && !self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
        newBounds.size.width -=32;
        newPosition.x -= 15;
    }
    //move back left
    else if (self.editing) {
        newBounds.size.width += 32;
        newPosition.x += 15;
    }
    self.myCALayer.bounds = newBounds;
    self.myCALayer.position = newPosition;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

... however, the animations are not performed synchronously. What happens is while the cell moves right when entering editing mode, first the width of the layer shrinks, and then the position changes. Although the layer finally fits the cell, the animation looks bad.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your layers, but you should be able to set a smart `autoresizingMask` on your subviews so they re-layout appropriately when the size of `contentView` is altered by the tableview (on entry to edit mode).

More [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)

Edit: with a little looking, I think `CALayer`'s `anchorPoint` property may help with your sublayers. (more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint))

Alternatively (and this is a bit of a hack, and could hurt performance somewhat), you could set your custom layers on a UIView w/ an appropriately set `autoresizingMask`.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks! By setting the `anchorPoint` to the very left, I only need to adjust the width of my `CALayer` when entering editing mode. However, I'm still struggling to get the implicit animation of the width change synchronized to the animation with which the delete buttons move in when entering editing mode. Any hints?

Comment: Are you using `CAAnimation` to change the layer size (via `-[addAnimation:forKey:]`)? If not, check it out here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514

Comment: Yep. Tried a lot of other things too. Still I'm not able to get both animations run simultaneously...

Comment: Hi again, Ben. Well, things are much simpler as I thought. Your hints were perfectly right. I just wasted too much time trying to explicitly animate the stuff, however, everything can easily be done with a correct initialization. I posted my final solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085159/simultaneous-animation-when-entering-editing-mode-of-uitableviewcell/)