# Simultaneous animation when entering editing mode of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

when entering the editing mode in a `UITableViewCell` through `setEditing:animated:`, there is an (implicit) animation where the cells move right and the delete "buttons" appear at the left.

How do I manage, probably with Core Animation features, to run a second animation *simultaneously* to the first animation when entering editing mode, i.e. with the the same starting time, duration, timing curve, and so on? (I'm actually trying to change the width of a cell's sublayer synchronously.)

I studied the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and tried some of the techniques in a custom `UITableViewCell` class, for example by overriding `willTransitionToState:`. In principle, everything works well, however, I can only manage to have the animations one after the other, but not simultaneously.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it's **much** simpler than I initially thought. The behavior I sought can rather easily be achieved by correctly initializing the layers (or views) in the custom `UITableViewCell`. However, I realized that the order and, e.g., whether you manipulate bounds or frame properties is quite important.

The following code snippet does the job for a cell in a *grouped* `UITableView`. In this example, a `CAGradientLayer` (as an example for a `CALayer`) is added as a sublayer to a `UIView`, which itself is added as a subview to `self.contentView` of the cell. The subview's frame is tweaked to fit into the contentView. The code goes, e.g., into `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` of a custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
CGRect realFrame = self.contentView.frame;
realFrame.size.width += 20;
UIView *gradientView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:realFrame];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
gradientLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.frame;
gradientLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
[gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil]];
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

gradientView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
gradientView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;

[gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
[self.contentView addSubview:gradientView];

gradientView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[gradientView release];
[gradientLayer release];
```